# Looping a random value in blender geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, workflow, loop

I'm searching for a way to use a random value node in geometry nodes in Blender 3.3 to start a looping motion. It should go from say 1 to 0 and then 0 to 1 back but start on a random positions that the random value give as the start.

Comment: I assume you are looking for the math node `Ping-Pong`. Just feed it with e.g. `Scene Time` (*Frame*) or another value that is incremental.

Answer (score 2):

Following quellenform's idea:

I think there might be much easier node setups ;) but it works:

[image]

[image]